# Group permissions

Tags: linux, permissions

I would like to learn how to do next stuff:

```
1) make for example /bin folder and everything inside visible only to root account

2) make for example /usr/etc/something have permissions like: read, write, execute only to root, read only for 'admin' group (so the permission rule can be applied to everyone in that group)

3) make for example /usr/etc/something2 have permissions like: read, write to group 'random'
```

I have tried using **chgrp** but I haven't seen in documentation that I can give specific permissions on specific directory for specific group. After I user for example **chgrp -R admin /usr/etc/something** and switch to account that is under 'admin' group, I can still see that directory and have the same rights as root. So my next goal is to make those 3 example working.

Comment: The exercises do not require you to use `chgrp -R` to change ownership of files ad directories beneath the mentioned directories, nor to change permissions on any files beneath the mentioned directories (as `chmod -R` would do). At best these commands would make it very difficult to restore the default permissions, and with of bad luck, it would require the system to be reinstalled. Backup your data before changing permissions on things like `/bin`.

Comment: It is fresh VM so there is no worry about making things wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing persmissionship and ownership. The first can be changed by chmod, the latter by chown(user and user/group) and chgrp(group only).

The following commands will do what you want:
    chmod 700 /bin; chown root:root /bin
    chmod 750 /usr/etc/something; chown root:admin /usr/etc/something
    chmod 750 /usr/etc/something2; chown root:random /usr/etc/something2

chmod will set the permissions, chown will set the ownerships. The combination is what you want.

Comment: I get it. So I don't need to worry about root part in root:random for example. I tought there is a way to speciffy only random (group part) cause it seems like an overhead to write for both root and random. Thank you.